# How can I use the node title in drupal as a contexual filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm working on a movie website and I have two content types, "Movies" and "Movie reviews". I want to make a view (using the views module) that shows me all of the "Movie Reviews" related to a movie.

I need to grab all the "Movie Reviews" that have the same content in the "Title" cck field as the title of the current "Movie" Node.

i.e. if I am viewing the "Madagascar" Movie node, I need to get all of the Movie Reviews with "Madagascar" in the title.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using an entity reference field.

1. Install this [http://drupal.org/project/entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
2. Add an entity reference field to your review content type that references the movie content type.
3. Create a new view displaying a list of reviews.
4. Add a contextual filter selecting the movie field, where it says "WHEN "THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" select Provide default value -> Content ID from URL.

If you have created the view with a block place the block so it can be seen on the movie page and it should only display reviews linked to that movie

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will give it a shot! I'm not very good with the filters in views yet, so how to do certain things is becoming increasingly more annoying.

Comment: actually creating relationships between content is the way to go it's much more robust and doesn't rely on spellings or punctuation etc